# Why autoincrement doesn't follow a sequential order

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a database in a server and I am rewriting my old program with c# . When I checked the ID's columns which are defined autoincremental I saw the result as shown on the pictures

1st table:

[image]

2nd table:

[image]

Any idea? I hadn't deleted any row and my command sql is still the same between Id 20 and 33 . The only difference after 20 I corrected my transactional writing data and it works. It can affect the increment of id ?

Comment: Any failed/rolled back transactions?

Comment: Yes, i'am in the developpement stage. But ID's 1,3,4 is the 1st insert statement then after. Under you remarq I will truncate the table (I'm in developpement stage)  as rollback/commit works perfectly I will check it. Thanks for idea.

Comment: `auto_increment` generates **unique** values, but doesn't guaranee that there are no gaps between adjacent values.

Comment: @Ismail Gunes: why do you care anyway? It's perfectly fine to have gaps in sequential PK